# C # SerialPort? I am writing code about reading com port address lamp that I sent,It's wrong

Tags: c#, serial-port

The code I declare the lamp address:

```
 byte[] on = { 0xe8, 0xff, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x02, 0x02, 0x02, 0x04, 0x82, 0x02, 0x01};
 byte[] off = { 0xe8, 0xff, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x02, 0x02, 0x02, 0x04, 0x82, 0x02, 0x00 };
```

Until it iterates twice, time 1 is the correct address and second is different numbers

```
 private void Data_Received(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            int i;
            Thread.Sleep(10);
            rec_lend = serialPort1.BytesToRead;
            rxbyte = new byte[rec_lend];
            serialPort1.Read(rxbyte, 0, rec_lend);
            for (i = 0; i < rxbyte.Length; i++)
            {
                
                rspdata.Enqueue(rxbyte[i]);
                MessageBox.Show(i.ToString() + rspdata.ToArray());
            }

            this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
            {
                req_msg();
            });
        }
    
        
        public void req_msg()
        {
            int i;
            if (rspdata.Count != 0)
            {
                byte[] messageReceive = new byte[rspdata.Count];
                int ghdata = rspdata.Count; 
                rec_msg = new byte[rspdata.Count];
               
                for (i = 0; i < 11; i++)
                {

                    rec_msg[i] = (byte)(rspdata.Dequeue());
                    dataOUT +=  Convert.ToString(rec_msg[i], 16);
                    
                    
                }
                
                if (rspdata.Count != 0)
                {
                    req_msg();
                }
            }
            tBoxDataIN.Text = dataOUT;
        }
```

I also don't know where I got stuck, causing it to repeat 2 times like this. It is very difficult for learners like me

Answer (score 0):

Try this, hope this code can help you:

```
private void SpDataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        SerialPort serialPort = (SerialPort)sender;
        string portName = serialPort.PortName;
        string str = serialPort.ReadExisting();
        try
        {
            byte[] numArray = new byte[serialPort.BytesToRead];
            if (serialPort.Read(numArray, 0, numArray.Length) <= 0)
                Console.WriteLine("No have data!");
            serialPort.Write(numArray, 0, numArray.Length);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            txtLog.AppendText("\r\n" + "SpDataReceived fail \n" + ex.ToString());// += ;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but I still can't execute the code. I did it in my opinion, even though the code has improved, the data still bounces back 2 times.